# Swift type casting issue

Tags: ios, swift, types, casting, crash

I have a weird crash (like 1 for 10 000 times), here is a code:

```
typealias APIData = Dictionary <String, AnyObject>

static func performAction(action: APIAction, params: APIParams, needAuthorization: Bool = true, completion: APICompletion) -> AFHTTPRequestOperation? {
    var requestParameters: APIParams = ["request": params]

    if needAuthorization && sessionIsValid() {
        requestParameters["session_id"] = sessionID!
    }

    APILogger.logAction(action, params: requestParameters)

    return API.requestManager.POST(action.rawValue, parameters: requestParameters, success: { (operation, data) -> Void in

        guard let _data = data as? APIData, errorCode = _data["errorCode"] as? Int, error = APIError(rawValue: errorCode) else {
            completion(state: .Failed, data: nil, error: .Undefined)
            return
        }

        if error == .NoError {
            if let responceData = _data["response"] as? APIData {
                APILogger.logData(_data)
                completion(state: .Success, data: responceData, error: error)
            } else {
                completion(state: .Success, data: nil, error: error)
            }
        } else {
            if error == .ExpiredSession {
                sessionID = nil
            }
            completion(state: .Failed, data: nil, error: error)
        }

        }) { (operation, error) -> Void in
            if operation.cancelled {
                completion(state: .Cancelled, data: nil, error: .Undefined)
            } else {
                completion(state: .Failed, data: nil, error: .Undefined)
            }
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
                Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
            0  libswiftCore.dylib             0x0000000100645cbc swift::_swift_getClass(void const*) + 24
            1  libswiftCore.dylib             0x000000010063d57c swift_getObjectType + 12
            2  libswiftCore.dylib             0x000000010062209c _dynamicCastFromExistential(swift::OpaqueValue*, swift::OpaqueValue*, swift::ExistentialTypeMetadata const*, swift::Metadata const*, swift::DynamicCastFlags) + 156
            3  libswiftCore.dylib             0x0000000100620e2c swift_dynamicCast + 496
            4  BenefitCalculator_iOS          0x000000010012a2ec static API.(performAction(API.Type) -> (APIAction, params : [String : AnyObject], needAuthorization : Bool, completion : (state : APIOperationState, data : [String : AnyObject]?, error : APIError) -> ()) -> AFHTTPRequestOperation?).(closure #1) (API.swift:43)
            5  BenefitCalculator_iOS          0x000000010012aa28 thunk (API.swift)
            6  BenefitCalculator_iOS          0x000000010012aa54 thunk (API.swift)
            7  BenefitCalculator_iOS          0x000000010012aab4 thunk (API.swift)
            8  libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000196fb1994 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
            9  libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000196fb1954 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
            10 libdispatch.dylib              0x0000000196fb620c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1608
            11 CoreFoundation                 0x00000001850f37f8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
            12 CoreFoundation                 0x00000001850f18a0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1492
            13 CoreFoundation                 0x000000018501d2d4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
            14 GraphicsServices               0x000000018e8336fc GSEventRunModal + 168
            15 UIKit                          0x0000000189be2fac UIApplicationMain + 1488
            16 BenefitCalculator_iOS          0x0000000100122f4c main (AppDelegate.swift:15)
            17 libdyld.dylib                  0x0000000196fdea08 start + 4
```

According to stack trace it's crashing here:

```
guard let _data = data as? APIData, errorCode = _data["errorCode"] as? Int, error = APIError(rawValue: errorCode) else
```

It's so hard to recreate this crash...

It's seems Swift type casting could crash even if I do it right (let _data = data as? APIData) and it's very rare. I would be very appreciated if someone could help me to solve this.

Comment: is the data in the api return NSData, NSObject, AnyObject or [String : AnyObject] type? It almost sounds like you are getting something back from your api call that is not the type you are expecting. An example would be you are expecting json back but all you get is an empty string so when you convert it it's just "" instead of a dictionary.

Comment: It's an AnyObject, and I have tested type casting with this type. There is actually shouldn't be any care about type, because guard let _data = dat as? APIData also chek If data nil and if it's an APIData.

Comment: hmm, i would try breaking that guard statement up to be on multiple lines to see if you can identify which section is making it crash. It seems accurate enough, but just for sanity's sake i would do it. Also what is the error above the stack trace?

Comment: I tried to break my guard to a multiple guard let... It still crashes on first one... It's very hard to get this crash.... It seems _swift_getClass(void const*) tell us about incompatible types, but I'm not sure... Can you also tell me how deep closures can be nested?

Comment: i don't think there is a limit to nested closures cause it's just a function call you can call a function in functions infinitely until you run out of memory, if you are referring to multithreading it's as limited as there are threads or cores on the 4 before it starts doing parallel processing

Comment: Well, there is only two threads, AFNetworing thread, where all network request made, and main thread.... Ty for your answers, I will be very appreciated if we could find out whats a problem))

Comment: I guess make sure all the data is valid before you start extracting it all it's all i can really think of with out having an example in front of me